# SQL Server | String Comparison

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, string-comparison

I am facing some strange issue and want to understand the reason behind this.

We have two database servers Say  A and B. On both of these servers we have our application database (Same schema but different records)

Problem :
We have a SqlQuery

```
Select * from Person where memberId=123456
```

This query runs perfectly and return the rows selected on server - A.
But the same query on a different server-B doesnt return any records.

But if i modify my query to

```
Select * from Person where memberId='123456'
```

( notice the single quotes)

Now it returns me proper records.

DataType of memberId is nchar(100) . Technically i understand that i should compare it using the single quotes.

But just want to understand why is this happening??

Update : 
1) Both have exactly the same schema.
2) Both have same records

Actual Code :

Actually this query is a dynamically created and then executed using

```
declare @sql varchar(2000)
    set @sql = 'SELECT * FROM PersonTrivia where memberId='+ @MemberId
    print @sql 
    exec (@sql)
```

and this parameter @MemberId is varchar(250)

Comment: Sorry to ask what might seem like an obvious question; you've double checked that the schema for both the tables is the same?

Comment: Interesting question but why on earth are you using a fixed width 200 byte column `nchar(100)` to store an int?

Comment: Which SQL Server versions are these (which is which)? Also, is the collation order for the field memberId the same?

Comment: Is there a `nchar` type in SQL Server 2005? In from MSDN, looks like it is not http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/ms182673%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: @Soner Gönül: But [of course](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms182673%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

Comment: @Soner - Yes there definitely is. According to the [data type precedence rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) when comparing an `nchar` column  to an `int` literal the column should get implicitly cast to an `int`, can't think of a way that these results can happen.

Comment: Thanks @Andriy, In Turkish MSDN there isn't look. But in English, there is :) Weird.

Comment: @Gaurav - Can you post your actual code that causes this issue? I assume you might have sanitised it a bit before posting and that has left out a crucial detail?

Comment: @Gaurav - Still clueless after your edit. Can you show the code that assigns to `@MemberId`. Also can you confirm does this happen for **all** rows or is it just some/one specific row?

Comment: hey Martin- this code is written in a stored Proc.

Comment: What happens if you do `Select * from Person where CAST(memberId AS INT)=123456` ?

Comment: I get 
The conversion of the nvarchar value '2318730233                                                                                       ' overflowed an int column. Maximum integer value exceeded.

Comment: So your query with a literal can't be passing `123456` then as that would cause a cast to `int` as well. Are you passing a floating point value? Please tell us the **actual** value.

Comment: @Martin- I know the query is not passing single quotes  but why does this work on SERVER A at the first place?  this is a string value

Comment: What is the value of `@MemberId` that you see this behaviour with? I assume if you actually try `123456` that you will get the error "conversion of the nvarchar value '2318730233 ' overflowed an int column" as per the explicit cast.

Comment: Also are you executing these queries directly from management studio or similar or your own code?

Answer (score 2):

Does the query return no records or it gives you an error?

It looks like you can enter numbers into a nchar field, however, the first time you add a character you won't be able to query for "integers" anymore... or at least it seems so.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testnchar](
    [id] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [name] [nchar](100) NULL
)
GO

insert testnchar
select 1, 222222

select * from testnchar 
where name = 222222

id         name
---------  --------
1          222222 

insert testnchar
select 1, 'test'

select * from testnchar 
where name = 222222

--Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
--Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'test       

delete testnchar 
where name = 'test'

select * from testnchar 
where name = 222222

id         name
---------  --------
1          222222
```

Comment: The definite implication from the OP is that they just get no results rather than an error though. That would be quite a crucial bit of information to leave out!

Answer (score 2):

I will be very interested to know if you come up with another reason for why this is occurring, but I am starting to doubt it. I am fairly certain you are catching or suppressing an error somewhere.

Consider the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [Person]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MemberID] [nchar](200) NULL,
    [Data] [varchar](50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )
)

INSERT Person([MemberID],[Data]) VALUES ('1111111111', 'Test1');
INSERT Person([MemberID],[Data]) VALUES ('2222222222', 'Test2');
INSERT Person([MemberID],[Data]) VALUES ('3333333333', 'Test3');
INSERT Person([MemberID],[Data]) VALUES ('NON-NUMERIC', 'Test4');

SELECT * FROM Person WHERE MemberID = 2222222222
```

The query above will return (1) result *AND* an error. So, if your code looked like the following:

```
command = new SqlCommand( 
     @"SELECT * FROM Person WHERE MemberID = 2222222222", connection );
try
{
    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while ( reader.Read() )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "MemberID = " + reader["MemberID"] );
    }
    // We'll never get here.
    reader.Close();
}
catch { }
```

The result you would get would be `MemberID = 2222222222`. This could also occur if you were using SQL `TRY...CATCH` blocks. However, if we change the order<sup>1</sup> of the records:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [Person]

INSERT Person([MemberID],[Data]) VALUES ('NON-NUMERIC', 'Test1');
INSERT Person([MemberID],[Data]) VALUES ('1111111111', 'Test2');
INSERT Person([MemberID],[Data]) VALUES ('2222222222', 'Test3');
INSERT Person([MemberID],[Data]) VALUES ('3333333333', 'Test4');
```

You will essentially get (0) results before the exception is thrown. Finally, if you changed your query to:

```
SELECT T.* FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 100 *
    FROM Person
    ORDER BY MemberID
) T
WHERE T.MemberID = 2222222222
```

... you'd get (1) record and an error.

My advice would be to find out if and why you are suppressing an error. My overall advice is to not compare a character field to an integer and rely on an implicit conversion.

<sup>1. Clustered indexes don't **guarantee** row order. It almost certainly will in this test, but it was worth pointing out.</sup>

Comment: I can't see any way that the literal `123456` could ever cause the described behaviour. Hopefully if the OP reveals the value they are actually using things will become clearer.

Comment: My guess is that the implicit conversion to int caused by 123456, or whatever value, is causing an error. The OP said the SQL is in a stored procedure, and I'm guessing it is being called from code that is handling errors. When you had him do the `CAST(memberId AS INT)` test, he probably did it from a query window, and not within the problem stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously `memberId` is converted to int before comparison (I assume there is no errors in query exec on 2nd machine?). So my first guess would be that this is machine of Sql Server culture specific, i.e. `memberId` can be converted to int on first machine and can't on other. Or, since records differ (?) there is just some "wrong" records on 2nd machine. However last thing should result in runtime error.

Comment: Petr- Not sure about SQL server culture Specific thing , cause both these servers are maintained by our hosting provider